# Adding a C/Common wire to HVAC system

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

So I'm looking for some help in identifying where I can attach a C/Common Wire to my HVAC system, but unfortunately my system doesn't have a control board that I can easily attach a powerkit to. For reference I'm planning to install an Echobee3.

I've uploaded some photos here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF52E.jpg

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, probably adding some circle/arrows so I know what you're talking about ;)

After looking at Tester101's answer, here's an annotated picture.
Notice how they're two free wires(red and black)
[image: annotated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new information... It looks like the blue wire from the secondary side of the transformer is the `R`, which would make the yellow secondary wire `C`.

I should have read the transformer label, that clearly says BL (Blue) is common, and yellow is 24V.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) How would you personally recommend me accessing that wire? Splitting it, etc.

Comment: @Icestorm Not sure, I can't really tell how it's terminated now.

Comment: Oh that comment was from when we thought the yellow wire was "C". If the black wire is common then it's easy. It just has a plastic cap on it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: **NO**! BL stands for **BLUE**. Your system is wired up so that the blue secondary wire is connected to the **red** `R` wire, so the **yellow** secondary wire is going to be your `C`.

Comment: Ah! Then you previous comment about not knowing how it was terminated makes sense. But I now know what wire I need.

Comment: @Icestorm Looks like there might be an unused terminal where the yellow `C` wire terminates, so you could use a [female spade connector](http://www.conrad.com/medias/global/ce/7000_7999/7300/7370/7375/737588_LB_00_FB.EPS_1000.jpg), to connect the wire from the thermostat.

Comment: Also note that it's common to use the blue wire in the thermostat cable as the `C` wire. So connect the unused blue wire from the thermostat cable, to the terminal mentioned before. Note. You might have to use a short bit of spare wire, and a twist-on wire connector to reach.

Comment: [Good eye](http://i.imgur.com/uUgErpi.png) considering the zoom on the original image. Final question, if I wanted to test the voltage with a multimeter, what would my second point be? Thanks again for saving me $150 :)

Comment: @Icestorm One probe will go to the wire labeled `R` in your image above, the other will go on the suspected `C` terminal.  You should measure about 24V (though it will likely be slightly higher).